# Getting objects from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

My problem:
I use the site API - https://www.themealdb.com/api.php .

I want to get a list of all products. For this purpose, the link is https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php

In my code, I created a structure:

```
struct Category: Decodable {
    var idCategory: Int?
    var strCategory: String?
    var strCategoryDescription: String?
    var strCategoryThumb: String?
}
```

Then I try to get to the address and get the data. I can convert the incoming data to JSON. It works.

[image]

Next, I want to convert the data and write it into an array of structures.

```
func load(url: String, completion: @escaping (_ objects: [Category])->()) {

    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            //let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            //print("JSONSerialization" + "\(json)")

            let object = try JSONDecoder().decode([Category].self, from: data)
            print("JSONDecoder" + "\(object)")
            completion(object)

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

But in this line I get an error in the console:

```
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

Probably a mistake in my structure. I can not deal with this problem.

Comment: `print(error.localizedDescription)` => `print(error)`. It will give you more explanation on the error.

Comment: I’d suggest the completion handler be `[Category]?`, or better, `Result<[Category], Error>` type so you can differentiate between empty result set and an error. This will be especially useful if the API has a filter/search capability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **two** mistakes.

1. The actual error

   > Type 'Array' mismatch: Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.

   indicates that you are ignoring the root object, the dictionary with key `categories`
2. The value for key `id` is `String` not `Int`, note the double quotes in the JSON

---

Declare all struct members as **non-optional** constants as the JSON provides all keys the in dictionaries. And please map the horrible dictionary keys to more meaningful member names.

And print all `error`s and **never** `.localizedDescription` in a `Decodable` catch block.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let categories: [Category]
}

struct Category: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let thumbnailURL: URL

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "idCategory"
        case name = "strCategory"
        case description = "strCategoryDescription"
        case thumbnailURL = "strCategoryThumb"
    }
}
```

---

```
func load(url: String, completion: @escaping ([Category]) -> Void) {

    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

    let session = URLSession.shared    
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in

        if let error = error { print(error); return }

        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
            print("JSONDecoder", response)
            completion(response.categories)

        } catch {
            print(error)
            completion([])
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two codables

```
struct MyData: Codable {
    var categories: [Category]?
}
```

And

```
let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyData.self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a wrapper class you can fetch your categories. The following code works fine in Playground:

```swift
let json = """
{
    "categories": [
        {"idCategory": "1"},
        {"idCategory": "2"}
    ]
}
"""

struct CategoryHolder: Codable {
    var categories: [Category]
}

struct Category: Codable {
    let idCategory: String?
    let strCategory: String?
    let strCategoryDescription: String?
    let strCategoryThumb: String?
}

let jsonData = Data(json.utf8)
let categories = try JSONDecoder().decode(CategoryHolder.self, from: jsonData).categories
```